# linking a static(.a) library with a shared (.so) library, getting error "relocation R_X86_64_32S against a local symbol; recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: c++, eclipse, 64-bit, fpic

Compiling with g++ 64 bit in redhat using eclipse.

Compile Error:
../lib-EL5-64bit/libskd3_clnt_30134500.a(skd_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Things I have tried
I added -fPIC to both the c++ compiler flags, as well as the linker flags. It already existed in the compiler flags, i just moved it to directly after the g++, and at the end of the list.

I've asked the creator of the .a library to recompile with -fPIC and it still gives the same error

Is there any way to make sure that their library was compiled with -fPIC?
Does the error message say that I need to compile my .so with -fPIC, or the .a file needs to be compiled with -fPIC?
What else can I check?

Here is the make file (auto generated by eclipse)

Make file:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include generic_d2s/subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: libFUSE.so

# Tool invocations
libFUSE.so: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -fPIC -L../../CRYPTOPP/lib-EL5-64bit -L../lib-EL5-64bit -Wl,-rpath /lib -shared -o"libFUSE.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(LIBRARIES)$(CPP_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) libFUSE.so
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

subdir.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../CRI.cpp 


C_SRCS += \
../client_rsa.c 

OBJS += \
./CRI.o 


C_DEPS += \
./client_rsa.d 

CPP_DEPS += \
./CRI.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
%.o: ../%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'
    g++ -D_TM_CDIR='"/proj/kronos/test/hho/testprograms/trunk/testmethods/FUSE"' -I../../CRYPTOPP/include/cryptopp -I"/opt/hp93000/soc/pws/lib" -I"/opt/hp93000/soc/com/include" -I/opt/hp93000/soc/prod_com/include -I/opt/hp93000/soc/prod_com/include/MAPI -I/opt/hp93000/soc/testmethod/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -shared -fPIC  -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunknown-pragmas -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o"$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

%.o: ../%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc -D_TM_CDIR='"/proj/kronos/test/hho/testprograms/trunk/testmethods/FUSE"' -I/opt/hp93000/soc/prod_com/include -I/opt/hp93000/soc/prod_com/include/MAPI -I/opt/hp93000/soc/testmethod/include -I/opt/hp93000/soc/com/include -I/opt/hp93000/soc/pws/lib -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC  -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunknown-pragmas -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o"$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

objects.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

USER_OBJS :=

LIBS := -lBB_IO_lib.0.1 -lskd3_clnt_30134500 -lcryptopp
```

sources.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

O_SRCS := 
CPP_SRCS := 
C_UPPER_SRCS := 
C_SRCS := 
S_UPPER_SRCS := 
OBJ_SRCS := 
ASM_SRCS := 
CXX_SRCS := 
C++_SRCS := 
CC_SRCS := 
OBJS := 
C++_DEPS := 
C_DEPS := 
CC_DEPS := 
LIBRARIES := 
CPP_DEPS := 
CXX_DEPS := 
C_UPPER_DEPS := 

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
. \
generic_d2s \
```

Comment: The archive (`.a`) has to be recompiled with `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 4):

When you compile statically, the assembler instructions will assume certain things about the locality of code, e.g. any jump is within 4GB of the jumping/calling instruction. (Assuming 64b x86). Shared libraries may be loaded further away than 4GB, so that jump/call wont fit.

When you compile with -fPIC (position independent code) - the compiler will ensure that the code and local data references are position indepdent, and arrange for calls/jumps outside of itself happen with the worst case/maximum addressing mode (eg full 64b).

When you get this error, as you have, the static library cannot jump to the shared library - the shortcuts above were taken. The only solution is a recompile with -fPIC. (Technically, the 32-bit jump may only be 5 bytes but you need 9 bytes [1 opcode + 8 for the addr]; so no amount of assembler cleverness can work around this - not without some other dastardly operation, like using INT instructions to provide a short hand jump).

Nowadays most everything can/should be compiled with -fPIC irrespective of being shared - unless performance is important.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an utterly different reason for this error.
It's worth noting that in addition to message in the title of this thread, I had one more error, namely:

```
:-1: error: [path]/lib.a(xxxxxx.cpp.o): warning: relocation against `_ZN7N........kEPcmmPv' in read-only section `.text'
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt`, I had such code:

```
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC  ${HEADERS}
    PRIVATE ${SOURCES}
    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
   AnotherLib
)
```

A `.cpp` (mentioned in the SOURCES) was the culprit. Removing `PRIVATE` fixed the problem.