# error: lib.a: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `...' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, linker

When building, linker throws this error:

Error:

> error: /home/m3/repos/editor/editorlib/src/clipper/build//libclipper.a(clipper.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZNKSt6vectorIN10ClipperLib8PolyNodeESaIS1_EE4sizeEv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I have built the `libclipper.a` by these commands:

```
cd editorlib/src/clipper
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
```

#### Tried

One possibility was that the Debug-Release mismatch, but as far as I checked, that as not a problem.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recompile with -fPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812185/how-to-recompile-with-fpic)

Comment: @M.A No actually, what I needed was specific CMake options =)

Comment: The CMake option you specified does the same as manually adding the `-fpic` option to the compiler command line (it wasn't in the accepted answer).

Comment: @M.A That's right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error cause might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285879/3405291). It got resolved by:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON ..
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64552011/3405291).